# How can we sort a vector of vectors based on a particular index?

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem called Disk Stacking. It basically gives you a 2d array of disks. Each sub array has 3 dimensions width,depth,height. We are required to stack the disks on top of each other such that the disk at the top has dimenstions lesser than dimensions of disks below it.

The first step in solving the problem is to sort the disks based on heights. Then compare the other two dimensions of the previous disks with the current disks....

However, My question isn't about the solution of the problem. My questions is regarding a statement I found in one of the C++ solutions of this problem.

```
sort(disks.begin(), disks.end(), [](vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b) { return a[2] < b[2];});
```

The above code is used to sort the disks array based on heights... Now I don't know how it works. Someone, please enlighten me regarding why are we using the function with two vectors a and b, and how is it working?

Comment: This is asking about basic C++ concepts that should be fully explained in every C++ textbook. Your C++ textbook should have plenty of examples of using `std::sort` with lambdas, with the explanation of how it works. This must be a vector of vectors getting sorted by the value in the 2nd index of each vector. It doesn't really make sense to copy/paste entire chunks of text from a typical C++ textbook here, so can you clarify exactly which parts of the explanation, or material from your textbook, regarding this topic, are unclear to you? Stackoveflow isn't really a replacement for a textbook.

Comment: If you want to sort a container holding elements of type `T`, the comparator would need to compare two values of type `T`. That's kind of obvious. Here, you sort a collection of elements of type `vector<int>` so the comparator takes a pair of `vector<int>` values.

Comment: If your textbook pre-dates [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) ... consider getting a new one. They've been practically available for a decade (although admittedly it's hard to guess what search term to use just from the syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is a "Lambda expressions". In this particular case, it's playing the role of `operator<`. That means, instead of conceptual `vec1 < vec2`, `std::sort` will call your function as `lambda(vec1, vec2)`. The function then decides if the `vec1` is "less than" `vec2` by means of comparing their 3rd elements.

This is a common pattern in C++. You can see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for more on `std::sort`.